# Passing data from child using props in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-component

I need update the number of coins each time a transaction is made, these are located in the in a template component, but I wan´t duplicate the function that brings the number of coins in each view that I need to load? I show you the code as I currently do, it works but that is not the optimal solution since I would repeat the function ** get_coins ** in each component child.

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { userService } from '../_services';
import Template from '../Layouts/Template';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faExternalLinkSquareAlt } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

function MyShopping() {

    useEffect(() => {
        get_coins();
    }, []);

    const [coins, setCoins] = useState([]);

    function get_coins(){
        userService.get_coins()
            .then(resultCoins => {
                setCoins(resultCoins);
            });
    }

    function remove_coins(){
        userService.remove_coins_data()
            .then(result => {
                if (result.status==200) {
                    get_coins();
                }
            })
    }

    return (
        <Template dataCoins={coins}>
            <div className="py-6">
                <Button variant="success" onClick={remove_coins}>
                    Remove <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faExternalLinkSquareAlt} />
                </Button>
            </div>
        </Template>
    );
    
}

export { MyShopping };
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Template = ({ dataCoins, children }) =>(
    <React.Fragment>
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" className="cs_principal_nav">
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
                <Nav>
                    <Nav.Link to="">
                        {dataCoins.expirables} Coins
                    </Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link to="">
                        {dataCoins.permanentes} Coins
                    </Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
            {children}
    </React.Fragment>
);

export default Template;
```

Thank you

Comment: This is an english site, would you please consider translating your post?

Comment: Of course, I'm new member, right now I translate them

Comment: I would move all the logic to the parent component and pass `coins` and `removeCoins` as props to `MyShopping`. Btw I would apply `useCallback` hook to `remove_coins`